# How to pass ui_locales from AuthorizeRequest to the controller

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

In Identityserver3 there was the SignInMessage that was created in the `AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator`. But in IdentityServer4 there is no SignInMessage passed to my Login action.

So how do I pass through the ui_locales that is given in the authorize call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I need to inject the `IIdentityServerInteractionService` in my controller. Then in my Login action I can get the authorization context like

```
var context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl);
```

This `context` contains the UILocales.