# asp.net core - Passing ui_locales to my IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, identityserver4

my application is composed by a asp.net core webapp client and a asp,net core webapi hosting the identityserver4.

I need to pass to my is4 the ui_locales to localize the login web form. How i do this ?

Thanks to this post [How to pass ui_locales from AuthorizeRequest to the controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45818102/how-to-pass-ui-locales-from-authorizerequest-to-the-controller)
 i know how to read inside the login controller but i don't know how i need to setup inside the client.

Thanks for help

Comment: Ok i've found the solution. In startup class, when i set the client i can write
options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
{
    OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
   {
      context.ProtocolMessage.UiLocales = "it-IT";
      return Task.CompletedTask;
   }
};
I think i have the same result with the : ontext.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter() but i haven't tested

Comment: Hello, how do you return that ui_locales after the user has logged in Idsv4?  When it redirects to the original client, we should display the correct localized website.  How did you achieve it?